# Heroku deploy failed on assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "small issue".
Trying to learn Ruby On Rails, and now i want to deploy my project on heroku.

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching rake 12.3.2
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
       Fetching json 1.8.6
       Installing rake 12.3.2
       Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
       Fetching minitest 5.11.3
       Installing minitest 5.11.3
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.3
       Installing builder 3.2.3
       Fetching erubis 2.7.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.4
       Installing crass 1.0.4
       Fetching rack 1.6.11
       Installing rack 1.6.11
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.1
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.1
       Fetching arel 6.0.4
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing arel 6.0.4
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching thor 0.20.3
       Installing thor 0.20.3
       Fetching ffi 1.10.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
       Installing multi_json 1.13.1
       Installing ffi 1.10.0 with native extensions
       Fetching pg 0.17.1
       Installing pg 0.17.1 with native extensions
       Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Fetching rdoc 4.3.0
       Installing rdoc 4.3.0
       Fetching tilt 1.4.1
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Fetching i18n 0.9.5
       Installing i18n 0.9.5
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
       Fetching nokogiri 1.9.1
       Installing nokogiri 1.9.1 with native extensions
       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Fetching activesupport 4.2.0
       Installing activesupport 4.2.0
       Fetching sdoc 0.4.0
       Installing sdoc 0.4.0
       Fetching uglifier 2.5.3
       Installing uglifier 2.5.3
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.2
       Installing globalid 0.4.2
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Fetching activemodel 4.2.0
       Fetching jbuilder 2.2.3
       Installing activemodel 4.2.0
       Installing jbuilder 2.2.3
       Fetching sass 3.7.3
       Fetching activejob 4.2.0
       Installing activejob 4.2.0
       Installing sass 3.7.3
       Fetching activerecord 4.2.0
       Installing activerecord 4.2.0
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
       Fetching loofah 2.2.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
       Installing loofah 2.2.3
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Fetching actionview 4.2.0
       Installing actionview 4.2.0
       Fetching actionpack 4.2.0
       Installing actionpack 4.2.0
       Fetching railties 4.2.0
       Fetching actionmailer 4.2.0
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Installing railties 4.2.0
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.0.3
       Fetching rails 4.2.0
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
       Installing rails 4.2.0
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.3
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.3
       Fetching turbolinks 2.3.0
       Installing turbolinks 2.3.0
       Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from sass:

       Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.

       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811

       Bundle completed (39.08s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_af4ee1266f205da440cd39f395d56ff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_af4ee1266f205da440cd39f395d56ff3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
       rake aborted!
       SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

After this i have so much errors, and after them:

```
Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried to:
1.Add "config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false" to my application.rb file.

2.Initialize RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

3.Delete application.css (actually, this css file is blank)

But i still can't deploy.

Maybe this can help you:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'uglifier',              '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  end
```

Database.yml file (maybe problem is here, idk):

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Mac OS X with macports:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_postgres_development
  pool: 5
  username: sample_postgres
  password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # The server defaults to notice.
  #min_messages: warning

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_postgres_test
  pool: 5
  username: sample_postgres
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_postgres_production
  pool: 5
  username: sample_postgres
  password:
```

Application.js file(actually blank):

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Hmmm,  can you copy paste the contents of your app/assets/javascript/application.js file for me please

Comment: @srng added,but it's acutally blank

Comment: How did you generate the gem file? Your rails version is a little old. Try deleting your gemfile.lock and running bundle update and bundle install again, somethings hanging around that shouldn't be.

Comment: @Kyskyn `SystemStackError` usually points to code that calls some method, that ends up calling the original method over and over again in a endless (or close to it) loop. Since it's happening during asset compile, perhaps you have an include or mixin that is including something else that includes the original, etc... No guarantee this is your issue, but what you posted is an indicator.

Comment: Deleted gemfile.lock , and used bundle install, but there is still problem :c

Comment: try adding                  gem 'sass-rails', "3.2.5"            to your gemfile, delete gemfile and bundle install again.

Comment: Added gem 'sass-rails','3.2.5' and deleted gemfile.lock , but after bundle install i have issue with not compatible versions.

Comment: hmmm, I'm going off of previous questions, is the warning coming from heroku or rails? And whats conflicting?

Comment: Your `application.js` file is actually not blank. The `//= require jquery` and subsequent lines are not comments, they're actually includes. It might be possible that something is happening around those includes that is causing recursive calls to itself... maybe try deleting it all?